# Python - Add timer (clock)

Tags: python-3.x

I recently did did a copy script where I backup data from one folder to another. I was able to add progress, how can I add time as the progress goes

:

```
def copyFilesWithProgress(src, dest):

    numFiles = get_tree_size(src)

    if numFiles > 0:
        makedirs(dest)

        numCopied = 0

        for path, dirs, filenames in os.walk(src):
            for directory in dirs:
                destDir = path.replace(src, dest)
                makedirs(os.path.join(destDir, directory))


            for sfile in filenames:


                srcFile = os.path.join(path, sfile)

                destFile = os.path.join(path.replace(src, dest), sfile)

                if not os.path.isfile(destFile):

                    shutil.copy2(srcFile, destFile)

                numCopied += os.path.getsize (srcFile)

                p.calculateAndUpdate(numCopied, numFiles)
        print
```

This is the output :
Copying files... ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣ ▣   100%

Just below the line I want to start a timer when script starts and stop when copy is done.

Thanks

Comment: use `datetime` package